# Rollback transaction in a Spring @Controller and show exception message in view

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, transactions

I have a Spring MVC controller and when an exception occurs I would like to show the exception message in the view and rollback the open transactions. The view contains a form like this:

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="registrationForm">
    <form:errors path="*" cssClass="error-message"/>
    ...
</form:form>
```

I would like to show the exception message in the view, using the `<form:errors ... />` feature. This is my current quite horrible solution:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView submitForm(@ModelAttribute("registrationForm") RegistrationForm registrationForm,
                         BindingResult result,
                         ModelAndView modelAndView,
                         HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception
{
    registrationValidator.validate(registrationForm, result);

    if(result.hasErrors())
    {
        return setupForm(modelAndView, registrationForm);
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            // ... Some non-transactional operations...

            // The following operation is the only one annotated with @Transactional
            // myExampleDao is @Autowired, can throw exception
            myExampleDao.createFoo(bar);

            // ... Other non-transactional operations...

            return new ModelAndView("redirect:successful");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw new RegistrationException(e, registrationForm, result);
        }
    }
}

@ExceptionHandler(value = RegistrationException.class)
public ModelAndView registrationExceptionHandler(RegistrationException e) throws Exception
{
    RegistrationForm registrationForm = e.getRegistrationForm();
    BindingResult result = e.getBindingResult();

    result.reject("exception", e.getMessage());
    Map<String, Object> model = result.getModel();
    return setupForm(new ModelAndView("registration", model), registrationForm);
}

private ModelAndView setupForm(ModelAndView modelAndView, RegistrationForm registrationForm) throws Exception
{
    Map<String,Object> model = modelAndView.getModel();
    model.put("currentYear", Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR));
    return new ModelAndView("registration", model);
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that when the exception is thrown, the transaction is not rolled back.

Can anyone help?

Thank you.

**Update:** slightly changed the question for better understanding

**Update:** found a quite horrible solution to display the exception message in the view. Still facing the problem with the transaction that is not rolled back when the exception is thrown.

**Update:** I changed `@Transactional` to `@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)` in the `MyExampleDao.createFoo(...)` method and now everything is working perfectly. This solution is still ugly IMO, does anyone have a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one suggested a better solution than my ugly one. Here is my solution that solved the problem I had:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView submitForm(@ModelAttribute("registrationForm") RegistrationForm registrationForm,
                         BindingResult result,
                         ModelAndView modelAndView,
                         HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception
{
    registrationValidator.validate(registrationForm, result);

    if(result.hasErrors())
    {
        return setupForm(modelAndView, registrationForm);
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            // ... Some non-transactional operations...

            // The following operation is the only one annotated with @Transactional
            // myExampleDao is @Autowired, can throw exception
            myExampleDao.createFoo(bar);

            // ... Other non-transactional operations...

            return new ModelAndView("redirect:successful");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw new RegistrationException(e, registrationForm, result);
        }
    }
}

@ExceptionHandler(value = RegistrationException.class)
public ModelAndView registrationExceptionHandler(RegistrationException e) throws Exception
{
    RegistrationForm registrationForm = e.getRegistrationForm();
    BindingResult result = e.getBindingResult();

    result.reject("exception", e.getMessage());
    Map<String, Object> model = result.getModel();
    return setupForm(new ModelAndView("registration", model), registrationForm);
}

private ModelAndView setupForm(ModelAndView modelAndView, RegistrationForm registrationForm) throws Exception
{
    Map<String,Object> model = modelAndView.getModel();
    model.put("currentYear", Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR));
    return new ModelAndView("registration", model);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't have transactions in your controllers. Put them in your service layer.

You can create an abstract controller class that implements exception handling like so (then each separate controller extends obviously) :

```
public class AbstractCtrl {

    @Resource(name = "emailService")
    private EmailService emailService;

    /*
     * Default exception handler, catchs all exceptions, redirects to friendly
     * error page and send e-mail does not catch request mapping errors
     */

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public String myExceptionHandler(final Exception e) {
    final StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    final PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
    e.printStackTrace(pw);
    final String strStackTrace = sw.toString(); // stack trace as a string
    emailService.sendAlertMail(strStackTrace);

    return "exception"; // default friendly excpetion message for user
    }
}
```

But DO NOT put transaction in your controllers, put them in Service layer classes.

Comment: Thank you @NimChimpsky. I need to show the exception message in the view, so your example doesn't work. That's why I do "result.reject("exception.thirdParty", e.getMessage());" in the catch.

Comment: @satoshi Its not difficult to add the message to model and return it with view.  Why do you want to show the exception to the user, are they developers ?

Comment: No, the exception message is a normal error that everyone can understand. The error has to be displayed in the view, which contains the registration form and the errors are shown with "<form:errors path="*" />"

Comment: Please see my edited question, I added some (maybe important) detail.

Comment: Could you explain why it's a bad idea to have transactions in the controllers? What are some bad things that can happen because of doing it that way?

Comment: well it will work. But you cant reuse code very well and it makes the code difficult to change at a later date.

Comment: It's a bad idea because Spring proxies are generated for classes with Transactional annotations on them. By default Spring will use JDK dynamic proxies (interface based). You might then find that your @Controller isn't a controller anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you have to manage transaction in a controller scope, open a session from the sessionFactory.

```
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
try{
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    // code

session.save(foo);


tx.commit();
}catch(Exception e){
tx.rollback();
}finally{

try{session.close();}finally{}

}
```